# AS3 - detect touch/click on StageVideo

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, stagevideo

I need to stop and remove a StageVideo when the user clicks the video. anybody know how to go about doing that?

Comment: **StageVideo** is not a descendant of the **DisplayObject** class, so it's not possible to do it directly. I think you should use **StageVideo.viewPort** property to figure the stage position and size of the video and put an interactive overlay (transparent fill **SimpleButton** or **Sprite**) for user to interact with.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you use to display the video. That will serve as a good starting point for someone to base an answer on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer may vary depending on implementation, at the most basic level, you'd do something like this where `v` is your StageVideo instance:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

function click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(v.viewPort.contains(e.stageX, e.stageY)){
        trace("stage video clicked!!!")
    }
}
```

Listen on the stage for a Click event, then see if the `x`/`y` coordinates of the mouse click are contained in the viewport of the `StageVideo`.

Though a more common approach is to put a transparent sprite over the video:

```
var videoOverlay:Sprite = new Sprite();
videoOverlay.graphics.beginFill(0,0);
videoOverlay.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, v.viewPort.width, v.viewPort.height);
videoOverlay.x = v.viewPort.x;
videoOverlay.y = v.viewPort.y;
addChild(videoOverlay);

videoOverlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoClick);

function videoClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("video Clicked");
}
```